# Missing Namespace Tcp in Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, tcpchannel

I want to develop a simple network programm and want to use TcpChannel in VS Community 2017, but that doesn't work because of missing Type/Namespace "System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp" what I found in several online tutorials. I also can't find a missing assembly that I could add to my project.

The errormessage is "Error  CS0234  The type- or namespacename "Tcp" is in Namespace "System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels" not available. (Maybe missing assembly reference.)"

I'm working with a german VS, I translated the message, maybe in original it is slightly different.

[Screenshot of missing TcpChannel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WlMl.png)

Comment: What is your project type and .net framework set for project ?

Comment: project type is C# Windows Desktop and framework is 4.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you have to do following.

1. Make sure that project framework setting is correct. I assume that you have check with 4.6.1
2. Make sure you have added reference of System.Runtime.Remoting (System.Runtime.Remoting.dll) assembly reference.

If this is true that it is good to go for TcpChannel.